# helper:all doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application_controller.rb I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   helper :all


   def test1?
      true
   end

   def test2?
      false
   end


end
```

I can an error if I try and put <%= test1? %> or test2 in my views.

It works if I add the methods like:

```
helper_method  :test1?, :test2?
```

But its a pain to do this for each method, is there a better way to globally add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the definition of `helper :all` wrong.

`helper :all` invokes `require` on all of your helper classes within the `app/helpers` directory.

In order to have the methods you provided be accessible in all views, you can move them to the `application_helper.rb` file.